# How to execute second query based on first query result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a situation where i need to `execute` a **second** `query` based on first `query` result.

here is my first query result:

```
id  current_date    starts_on   ends_on Product_id  days_remaining
1   2017-06-21T12:00:00 2017-06-20T12:00:00Z    2017-06-23T12:00:00Z    3   2
2   2017-06-21T12:00:00 2017-06-01T12:00:00Z    2017-06-03T12:00:00Z    4   0
3   2017-06-21T12:00:00 2017-06-01T12:00:00Z    2017-06-03T12:00:00Z    7   0
4   2017-06-21T12:00:00 2017-07-01T12:00:00Z    2017-07-03T12:00:00Z    5   12
```

Here you can see `remaining_days` having 2 **zeros(0)** as result  on that occurence i want to get all `product_name` from `product` table

> My Both the Tables and Query for Above result is implemented but for
>   getting product_name is not implemented. please help me here

**here is my sqlfiddle:**  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bf34/1

**MY QUESTION:**  i want to get all `product_name` if `days_remaining` (see above result)  is 0

> in short get all product_name if days_remaining is 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
SET @mycurrentDate = '2017-06-21T12:00:00';
SELECT p.product_name, tn.* FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        @mycurrentDate AS `current_date`,
        `tn`.`start` AS `starts_on`,
        `tn`.`end` AS `ends_on`,
        `tn`.`product_id` AS `Product_id`,
        IF(`tn`.`end` >= @mycurrentDate, DATEDIFF(`tn`.`end`, @mycurrentDate), 0) AS `days_remaining`
    FROM `booking` AS `tn`
)tn LEFT JOIN product p ON tn.`Product_id` = p.product_id AND tn.`days_remaining` = 0
-- WHERE tn.days_remaining = 0
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bf34/18/1

**explanation:**

I wrapped your query into a `FROM` and `LEFT JOIN` to your result the table `product` on its identity `product_id`. Additionaly the `LEFT JOIN` is only matching if the `days_remaining` is zero.

If you want to filter the results to show only the records with `product_name` you have to add the following line at the end of this solution: `WHERE tn.days_remaining = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in a WHERE like this:

```
SELECT 
    tn.id, 
    p.product_name,
    @mycurrentDate AS `current_date`,
    `tn`.`start` AS `starts_on`,
    `tn`.`end` AS `ends_on`,
    `tn`.`product_id` AS `Product_id`
FROM `booking` AS `tn`
JOIN product as `p` on p.product_id = tn.product_id
WHERE IF(`tn`.`end` >= @mycurrentDate,
         DATEDIFF(`tn`.`end`, @mycurrentDate), #show days until event ends
         0 #the event has already passed
    ) = 0
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bf34/25

Edit: Not exactly a second query, but the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

using your own query, I expanded it:

```
#assume this is the date as NOW()
SET @mycurrentDate = '2017-06-21T12:00:00';
SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id IN (
  SELECT product_id FROM (
    SELECT 
      id, 
      @mycurrentDate AS `current_date`,
      `tn`.`start` AS `starts_on`,
      `tn`.`end` AS `ends_on`,
      `tn`.`product_id` AS `Product_id`,
      IF(`tn`.`end` >= @mycurrentDate,
         DATEDIFF(`tn`.`end`, @mycurrentDate), #show days until event ends
         0 #the event has already passed
      ) AS `days_remaining`
    FROM `booking` AS `tn`
  ) tmp1
  WHERE `days_remaining` = 0
)
```